# Go map has duplicate keys

Tags: go

I'm working on a small Go program that receives an ascii message over UDP. I want to look up the first field in the message and see if it exist in a map. Go thinks the key does not exist in the map but it does. I can add the key to the map and it creates a new entry, so I have two entries with the same key. I'm I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

EDIT:
 I've simplified the test down to remove the UDP and YAML.

https://play.golang.org/p/2Bg8UjhfWC

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type TestCase struct {
    Test string
    Result string
}

func main() {
    tcmap := make(map[string]TestCase)
    tcmap["adc"] = TestCase{Test: "/bar"}
    fmt.Printf("TestMap: ----------\n%v\n\n", tcmap)

    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    buf[0] = 'a'//0x61
    buf[1] = 'd'//0x64
    buf[2] = 'c'//0x63

    fmt.Printf("Received: ---------\n%v\n\n", string(buf[0:3]))
    fmt.Printf("Compare hex:-------\n|%x| |%x|\n\n", buf[0:3], "adc")

    // Get the first field from the message
    testname := strings.Split(strings.Trim(string(buf), " "), " ")[0]
    fmt.Printf("Test Name: |%v|\n", testname)

    // Does the key exist in the map?
    if t, ok := tcmap[testname]; ok {
        fmt.Printf("Test found: %v\n", t)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Test NOT found\n")
    }

    // Add testname to map, does it replace existing?
    tcmap[testname] = TestCase{Test: "/foo"}
    fmt.Printf("\nMAP: ---------\n%v\n\n", tcmap)
    fmt.Printf("KEY adc:---------\n%v\n\n", tcmap["adc"])
    for k,v := range tcmap {
        fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", k, v)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TestMap: ----------
map[adc:{/bar }]

Received: ---------
adc

Compare hex:-------
|616463| |616463|

Test Name: |adc|
Test NOT found

MAP: ---------
map[adc:{/bar } adc:{/foo }]

KEY adc:---------
{/bar }

adc: {/bar }
adc: {/foo }
```

Comment: You should remove all the UDP and other stuff not related to map. Try to provide simple code sample.

Comment: Try to get the value of the key in the map and compare it to the value of `testname` - they can look same but be different. For example `adc` and `аdс` - looks similar but have 2 different characters.

Put your code sample to play.golang.org

Comment: Thanks for updating the code sample. But, 1st you are checkign hex not of the map key. try to move print of hex inside of range. 2nd. I guess the issue is with the way you get the test name. Try to print len(testname) - proabably the 0 bytes are simply not printed so you think it's just 'adc' but in reality it is 'adc\x0\0....'

Comment: Key length was the issue. One was len=3, the other len=1024. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Alexander, the issue is the length between the two keys are different. One key has the length of 3 and the other has the length of 1024. The first three bytes were the same and on the longer key the remaining bytes were 0x00.

So the string output of the two keys make it appear the two are identical, but this was fooling me. The length of the keys was different.

Answer (score 2):

One of the keys has a trailing newline.  If you use `strings.TrimSpace` instead of `strings.Trim` you'll see that the trailing newline is trimmed and there is no duplicate.

Comment: If you use TrimSpace, it still doesn't work. There is no newline. The issue was the number of byte between the two keys were different.

Comment: Yes, that's true... upvoted your answer :) (TrimSpace _did_ work for me... maybe it was a fluke that the extra bytes in my test runs were newlines)